# Render select Tag from jQuery Ajax , then get the value from selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Problem** :

I create tag element (`<select>` ) from Ajax jQuery, but sometimes i can't get the value from its, and sometimes i can get it.

**Picture** 1 *before Ajax :
[image]

**Picture** 2 *after Ajax :
[image]

Assumptions the elements id is : proyek.

When i tried to console it : `$('#proyek').val()` , it says `undefined`, but after i reload and try again the proccess it says it has value `17` (right value).

So sometimes i can get the value, and sometimes i cant.

---

**Whole code** :

html : `<span id="generateProyek"></span>`

jQuery : `$("#generateProyek")
            .load("{{ 
                      this.url.getBaseUri()~"companyprojectdetail/ajaxproyek/"
                   }}"+id,function(){});`

> *note : i use volt, it use `{{ }}` to echo something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can't directly address an element that has been created after the page has been loaded.
To get this done, use delegation.
Since I don't have a bigger picture of your code I'll demonstrate a situation:

We have a div: `$('#to_be_loaded_into')`
Now when we click on `$('#proyek')` (which is created with ajax request) we want to get the value:

```
$('#to_be_loaded_into').on('click, '#proyek', function(){
console.log($('#proyek').val();
)};
```

edit: trying to get more specific for your elements, it just might be:
`$('#generateProyek').on('click, '#proyek', function(){
    console.log($('#proyek').val();
    )};`

I must first address an element that has been loaded into the html, and than refer to element inside it that has been renderd dynamically

Comment: can i assume that `$('#to_be_loaded_into')` == `$('#generateProyek')` ..?

Comment: do u mean that i must use this : `$('#generateProyek #proyek').click(function(){ console.log('#proyek').val() ; })`

Comment: I'd be honest here and say that i never used `.click()`.
`.on('event', 'delegation[optional], function(){})` Makes more sense for me. But check the jquery docs for `.click()` parameters to see if it suits your needs

Comment: please review my whole code, i edit it.. i'm wrong when i use `#ajaxProyek` thats i mean `#generateProyek`

Comment: Does `#ajaxProyek` exists in the HTML when the page is first loaded?

Comment: yep.. i will accept your answer if its work.. i never thought that i must use some kinds of delegation.. but i will try it later.. thanks for your kindness

Comment: i was got the solution.. another ajax clean the `onchange` event listener there, i just need to remove that ajax.. but thx for your appreciate